# Ошибка при foreach

Tags: c++, указатели, for

Почему ругается?
 Хочу пройтись по этим символам циклом.

```
 void binarystream::write(char bytes[]) {
        for (char byte : bytes)
        {

        }
    }
```

Вот такая ошибка:

```
не найдена соответствующая функция "begin", необходимая для этого основанного на диапазоне оператора for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данное объявление функции

```
void binarystream::write(char bytes[]);
```

эквивалентно следующему объявлению функции

```
void binarystream::write(char *bytes );
```

так как при объявлении параметра функции в виде массива переменная массива преобразуется в указатель на объект с типом, соответствующим типу своих элементов. А указатель не хранит информацию о том, указывает он на единственный объект, либо на первый элемент массива.

Поэтому в этом цикле

```
    for (char byte : bytes)
    {

    }
```

компилятор ищет функцию `begin` для указателя, которая не определена для указателей.

Поэтому лучше всего эту функцию объявить так, чтобы она принимала второй аргумент,задающий количество элементов в массиве, на первый элемент которого указывает первый параметр функции:

```
void binarystream::write(char bytes[], size_t n);
```

Тогда бы вы могли написать цикл в виде

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
{
   // используете выражение bytes[i]
}
```

или в виде

```
for ( char *first = bytes; first != bytes + n; ++first )
{
       // используете выражение *first
}
```

Другой подход - это объявить шаблонную функцию в виде

```
template <size_t N>
void binarystream::write(char ( &bytes )[N] );
```

Где массив передается по ссылке. В этом случае вы действительно можете использовать цикл

```
    for (char byte : bytes)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

При такой передаче - `char bytes[]` - передается только указатель на первый элемент массива. Вызванная функция даже не подозревает о том, сколько там элементов и есть ли они вообще...

Вариант - передавайте количество элементов типа

```
void binarystream::write(char bytes[], size_t N) 
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        char byte = bytes[i];
```

или, если размер массива известен при компиляции - используйте (если будете передавать массивы разных размеров) шаблон наподобие

```
template<size_t N>
void binarystream::write(char (&bytes)[N])
```

или, если передается только массив одного конкретного размера, просто функцию

```
void binarystream::write(char (&bytes)[10])
```

Answer (score 1):

Тип параметра функции `char bytes[]` неявно изменяется на `char *`, то бишь голый указатель. Соответственно использовать цикл for each с одним указателем нельзя. Передавайте массив по ссылке или используйте `array_view`